# String from list of bytes?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, byte, python-2.x

Very frustrated trying to convert a python list into a string but it keeps turning single bytes into 3 byte objects.

My code gets bytes from an i2c connection and stores them in a list. Its supposed to send them over the network as a string object and it does that. However on the java side at my computer a single byte such as 254 is literally

```
00110010 
00110101
00110100
```

instead of `11111110`.

Please advise?

Right before conversion, I print the array to my screen:

```
print("outgoing")
print(outgoing)
```

This is the print screen result:

```
outgoing
[254, 5, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 0, 202]
```

I attempted to convert the list into a single string as follows:

```
st = ''
try:
    for e in outgoing:
        st += str(e)
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print(e)
print(st)
```

I've tried multiple other ways to convert it.
My method writing to the network takes a string object and everything works fine throughout otherwise.

Comment: ''.join(str(e) for e in outgoing)

Comment: `''.join([chr(b) for b in outgoing])`? Also, look into the `struct` module for more sophisticated binary data manipulation. It doesn't look like you want Unicode representation, so you can try `struct.pack`.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? I find it strange that your method that writes to a network would take a `str` object, which in Python 3 is a sequence of unicode code points... it would make sense for it to take a *sequence of bytes*, i.e. a Python 2 `str` or a Python 3 `bytes` object...

Comment: I tried both comments above with no luck . Still going to look into struct module. Version 2.7 on a pi. I believe I could rewrite a bunch of other methods to use the list of bytes but it seems there should be a way to concatenate bytes together.

Comment: @cagney ok, you should really point out when you are using Python 2, note, it is no longer officially supported and is passed it's official end of life. When it comes to strings/bytes, it is a *very important* distinction between Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: you are concatenating *the string representations of those numbers together*, not the bytes themselves. There may be a better way in Python 2, but: `st = str(bytearray(outgoing))` should work... Heck, `bytearray(outgoing)` may work by itself.

So, to be clear, what you *were* doing is essentially:

```
>>> outgoing = [254, 5, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 0, 202]
>>> st = ''.join(map(str, outgoing))
>>> st
'254502552552552552552552552540202'
```

But that isn't what you want, you want:

```
>>> str(bytearray(outgoing))
'\xfe\x05\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\x00\xca'
```

Although, as I stated, depending on whatever client you are using,

```
>>> bytearray(outgoing)
bytearray(b'\xfe\x05\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\x00\xca')
```

might very well be enough.

Note, if anyone is in a similar situation on Python 3, then you want simply:

```
>>> outgoing = [254, 5, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 0, 202]
>>> bytes(outgoing)
b'\xfe\x05\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\x00\xca'
```

Comment: thanks for replying. the answers did not apply to my situation and in order to test the last answer I upgraded my pi to py3. However this broke a bunch of other code. Since im not really a python expert Im back to unit testing each method. Ill post result here after. not sure how relevant they will be at that point though

Comment: @cagney what didn't work with the Python 2 solutions?

Comment: yesterday I was throwing things at the wall and did not record my results. I'm sorry. My after the fact assessment was that I may have had a list of mixed types of objects. see post for more

Answer (score -1):

Being terrible at python and feeling like a toddler without a cookie I had two options.

One was to use the append the string with prefixing zeros in python to make the string representation that python gave me work in my code elsewhere.

The second was to create this travesty in python code as follows. Thanks for the advice as I did upgrade my pi to py3 and it led me in the right direction.

As you can see Im using pybluez and smbus2 to facilitate a data transfer. If there is a better example out there I sure wouldn't mind seeing it.

```
def move_data(bus, incoming):
if not incoming:
    return ""
#print('incoming')
#print(incoming)
readfail = 1
add = b'\x00'
adloc = 0
data = []
outgoing = []
outgoing.append(b'\xfe')
info = [incoming[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(incoming), 1)]
#print(info)
for s in info:
    #print(s)
    i = struct.unpack('<c', s)
    #print(i[0])
    if i[0] == b'\xfe':
        #print("254")
        if add != b'\x00':
            #print("add")
            if len(data) > 0:
                #print("send data")
                #print(add)
                #print(data)
                write_slave(bus, add, data)
                print("sent")
                outgoing.append(add)
                while readfail == 1:
                    try:
                        print("stuck")
                        time.sleep(.005)
                        addlist = list(add)
                        var = read_slave(bus, addlist[0], 8)
                        print("stuck---")
                        readfail = 0

                    except:
                        pass

                print("return data")
                print(var)
                now = bytes(var)
                print(now)
                rtn = [now[i:i + 1] for i in range(0, len(now), 1)]
                for e in rtn:
                    q = struct.unpack('<c', e)
                    outgoing.append(q[0])
                outgoing.append(b'\xfe')
            readfail = 1
            add = b'\x00'
            del data[:]
        else:
            adloc = 1
    elif adloc == 1:
        add = i[0]
        adloc = 0
        #print("added add")
    else:
        data.append(i[0])
        #print("added data")
outgoing.append(add)
outgoing.append(data[0])

    #ad = mlist
    #if ad != 0:
        #if s != '':
            #write_slave(bus, ad, s[2:])update to python 3
        #fromParts += ad
        #fromParts += read_slave(bus, ad, s[2:].len())
        #fromParts += b'fe'
#print_string(out)
print("outgoing")
print(outgoing)

#st = ''.join([chr(b) for b in outgoing])

#st = bytearray(outgoing)

#st = b''
#try:
    #for e in outgoing:
        #if e < 100:
            #st += '0'
            #if e < 10:
                #st += '0'
        #st += str(e)
#except:
    #e = sys.exc_info()[0]
   # print(e)
st = b''.join(outgoing)
#print(st)
return st
```

Here is where I send it for writing...dont laugh

```
def write_slave(bus, add, data):
st = b''.join(data)
datlist = list(st)
addlist = list(add)

bus.write_i2c_block_data(addlist[0], cmdReq, datlist)
```